# Internet Explorer Status Spin Wheel keeps spinning

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a weird problem, the Internet Explorer Status Spin Wheel keeps spinning on one of my ASP.NET website's login page even if the page is completely loaded. This is affecting our Performance testing as we cannot actually note the page load time etc. I tried the Multimedia option under tools menu but it didn't help.

Any help in this regards is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the page allow you to login still? I have had a similar issue where the page could not connect to the database and was continually reloading, if the page logs errors check its not stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @WraithNath I am able to login, everything works as expected. Its just the spinning wheel is driving me crazy.

Comment: Not really anything else I can suggest then really, when it happened to me the page was in a loop but your situation sounds different

Comment: It's a **spin wheel**. Of course it's spinning! It has to spin in order to be what it is. It can't perform such ontological change as becoming a **static wheel**. That would violate the proper order of the universe! You may as well ask a cube to look round...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem with the following steps:

1. Close all Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer windows.
2. Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button, and then clicking Internet Explorer.
3. Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.
4. Click the Advanced tab, and then click Reset.
5. Click Reset.
6. When you are done, click Close, and then click OK.
7. Close Internet Explorer and reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Comment: The problem with this answer is you're not going to be able to affect it on other users' PCs.